# Is there a better way to write this code without having to use so many table queries?

Tags: sql, optimization

am new to this coding lark and dont want to tell you how long it took me to get the output below... it does do what i wanted but im sure there must be a more efficient way to achieve it, ive spent that long on it now though that i cant see anything else!

```
WITH

Italian_Sales as(
 SELECT sum(od.quantityOrdered) as total_it, od.productCode as product_it
   FROM orderdetails as od
   JOIN orders as o
 ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
   JOIN customers as c
     ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
   JOIN products as p
     ON p.productCode = od.productCode
  WHERE c.country in ("Italy")
  GROUP BY product_it
),

Spanish_Sales as(
 SELECT sum(od.quantityOrdered) as total_sp, od.productCode as product_sp
   FROM orderdetails as od
   JOIN orders as o
 ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
   JOIN customers as c
     ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
   JOIN products as p
     ON p.productCode = od.productCode
  WHERE c.country in ("Spain")
  GROUP BY product_sp
),

French_Sales as(
 SELECT sum(od.quantityOrdered) as total_fr, od.productCode as product_fr
   FROM orderdetails as od
   JOIN orders as o
 ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
   JOIN customers as c
     ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
   JOIN products as p
     ON p.productCode = od.productCode
  WHERE c.country in ("France")
  GROUP BY product_fr
),

UK_Sales as(
 SELECT sum(od.quantityOrdered) as total_uk, od.productCode as product_uk
   FROM orderdetails as od
   JOIN orders as o
 ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
   JOIN customers as c
     ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
   JOIN products as p
     ON p.productCode = od.productCode
  WHERE c.country in ("UK")
  GROUP BY product_uk
),

Total_Sales as(
 SELECT sum(od.quantityOrdered) as total_sales, od.productCode as product_total
   FROM orderdetails as od
   JOIN orders as o
 ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
   JOIN customers as c
     ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
   JOIN products as p
     ON p.productCode = od.productCode
  WHERE c.country in ("Spain", "France", "UK", "Italy")
  GROUP BY product_total
)

SELECT p.productCode, p.productLine, p.productName, ts.total_sales as "Total Sales", its.total_it as    "Italian Sales", 
       ss.total_sp as "Spanish Sales", fs.total_fr as "French Sales", us.total_uk as "UK Sales"
  FROM products as p
  LEFT JOIN Italian_Sales as its
    ON p.productCode = product_it 
  LEFT JOIN Spanish_Sales as ss
    ON p.productCode = product_sp
  LEFT JOIN French_Sales as fs
    ON p.productCode = product_fr
  LEFT JOIN UK_Sales as us
    ON p.productCode = product_uk
  LEFT JOIN Total_Sales as ts
    ON p.productCode = product_total
 GROUP BY p.productCode
 ORDER BY ts.total_sales DESC;
```

the desired output is below with the sales for each country and the total amount but also showing null values where applicable (this is what took me ages before i remembered left join)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3dgD.png)

Comment: This would be a good candidate for `PIVOT`

Comment: Rather than all the individual, almost identical , queries, just include country in the group by of one query (and add a WHERE clause filter on the countries if you need to restrict them)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard `PIVOT`, especially given the aggregate, however there is an even simpler method you can use... `SUM(CASE)`

All of your sub-queries are identical except for the filter, so we can use the filter as the condition for a `CASE` statement and can return the value we want to count *only* when the row matches the filter criteria and return a zero or null for all other records. So we replace each subquery with a separate `CASE`:

```
SELECT p.productCode, p.productLine, p.productName
     , SUM(od.quantityOrdered) AS [Total Sales]
     , SUM(CASE c.country WHEN 'Italy' THEN od.quantityOrdered END) AS [Italian Sales]
     , SUM(CASE c.country WHEN 'Spain' THEN od.quantityOrdered END) AS [Spanish Sales]
     , SUM(CASE c.country WHEN 'France' THEN od.quantityOrdered END) AS [French Sales]
     , SUM(CASE c.country WHEN 'UK' THEN od.quantityOrdered END) AS [UK Sales]
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderdetails od ON p.productCode = od.productCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers c ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
GROUP BY p.productCode, p.productLine, p.productName
```

When you start to get too many terms, an actual PIVOT query might be simpler, but for now this is very manageable.